# Why the BindAttribute should be declared static

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    private string attrNames= "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price";

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = attrNames)] Movies movies)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(movies).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(movies);
    }
```

Why attrNames should be declared static?? Is it the correct way to use, just experimenting

*New to .Net MVC 5

Comment: Parameters must be constants - from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) _"Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values ..."_

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke For the doc link